# How can these strings be different?

Tags: character-encoding

I am facing a weird problem.

I have extracted data from an Excel file. It should contain an IBAN account number.

Then I tried to analyze the set of account numbers (which the source guarantees to be good) with a Java library.

To keep the scope of the question narrow, I can't explain the following. The below strings are different

```
030​69
03069
```

The first is a copy & paste from the Excel file, the second is handwritten. Google returns different results for `abi [above number]` and in fact in the second case I can find that it is the bank code for [Intesa Sanpaolo](https://www.intesasanpaolo.com) bank (exact page displaying the ABI code, localized, [here](https://www.intesasanpaolo.com/dati-societari/dati%20societari.jsp)).

So, to keep the scope narrow: how is that possible? Is it something to do with the encoding?

Try it yourself: do CTRL+F and try type "030", it will select both lines. Now type 6, it will match only the 2nd line.

Same happened in Notepad++

Comment: Is the Excel file the root source of your data?

Comment: No, but I have currently no information about how the Excel file was formed. It could have been copied&pasted from another source. Currently, from my point of view, it is my Java application's only source for data

Comment: If `03069` (with no spaces) be the correct bank code, then maybe you can try removing spurious white space in your Java code.

Comment: editing for an important clarification. If you try to find the string using ctrl+f you will get only the second. anyway I trimmed the strings already. Those are part of IBAN codes with spurious trailing spaces I have already disposed of

Comment: I'm not talking about trailing spaces, but rather whitespace in between a single code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an [`U+200B` ZERO WIDTH SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200B/index.htm) in between `030` and `69` in the first text.

Paste the text in https://www.branah.com/unicode-converter for example, or edit in a hexadecimal capable editor.

The solution for cleaning such strings could be for example to whitelist characters, so replace everything that isn't `A-Z0-9` will be scrubbed.